# Cannot share a photo to facebook using facebook android API

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to share a photo to facebook from my android app. I am following below guides to do it.

[Getting Started Android SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started)

[Sharing on Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android)

Following is the code I use to share.

```
if (ShareDialog.canShow(SharePhotoContent.class)) {
    SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder().setBitmap(bitap).build();
        SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder().addPhoto(photo).build();
        shareDialog.show(MyActivity.this, content);
}
```

I have created a facebook app in facebook developer console, added my debug and release key hashes to facebook application, added the facebook application ID to the android app manifest as specified in the guide and have done everything as specified in the guide.

But, when I share the photo, facebook share dialog appears for couple of seconds and disappears. Following is logged in Logcat.

```
04-11 12:51:42.692     443-9537/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Scheduling restart of crashed service com.facebook.orca/com.facebook.push.mqtt.service.MqttPushService in 1000ms
04-11 12:51:42.895  22617-22824/com.facebook.katana W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue﹕ Exception during service
    com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiException: [code] 100 [message]: Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api [extra]:
            at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.b(ApiResponseChecker.java:104)
            at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.a(ApiResponseChecker.java:137)
            at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.a(ApiResponseChecker.java:234)
            at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.a(ApiResponseChecker.java:185)
            at com.facebook.http.protocol.JsonResponseHandler.a(JsonResponseHandler.java:34)
            at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseHandler.b(ApiResponseHandler.java:91)
            at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseHandler.a(ApiResponseHandler.java:54)
            at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseHandler.handleResponse(ApiResponseHandler.java:29)
            at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:768)
            at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:245)
            at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:177)
            at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:73)
            at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor$Dispatcher.run(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:956)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at com.facebook.common.executors.ConstrainedListeningExecutorService$Worker.run(ConstrainedListeningExecutorService.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at com.facebook.common.executors.NamedThreadFactory$1.run(NamedThreadFactory.java:38)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

How can I find the reason why this happens? Is there a way to get more information on why the get request is unsupported?

Answer (score 0):

From the log error, I guess there's something wrong with the permission. Can you make sure you use the login process correctly? Or you can paste your full code.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by login process? I have initialized Facebook API by calling `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());` in `onCreate` method of activity

Comment: Sorry my fault. So you didn't implement facebook login in your app... That's fine. The error 100 usually thrown for authority issue. Can you check if you can do other action with facebook sdk in your app? e.g., posting or fetch friends?